# How to get the watch face that's on the Apple Watch box?

Tags: apple-watch

I've browsed through all the available Apple Watch faces, but I can't find the watch face (all white background with no markings or numbers) that is on the Apple Watch box.  Anyone know where I can find this or if it is possible to set it?

[image: Apple Watch Face]

Answer (score 1):

Edit 2: watchOS 5.1 does allow you to do fullscreen color watch faces, but the hands do not match the color on the box.

Original: After doing some looking, this watch face simply does not appear to actually exist as an option in watchOS 5.0.

Edit 1: It looks like a similar full screen color watch face exists in iOS 12’s watch face gallery, but it doesn’t work properly on the Apple Watch; it simply shows as a standard numberless dial.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Where is this "Face Gallery"?

Comment: @WilliamEntriken: The Face Gallery can be found in the Watch app on your iPhone.